# How to execute .sh file (raspberrypi) that is present in someother folder

Tags: linux, shell, script, shell-script, raspberry-pi

Sh file name: `runme.sh`
Path: `/home/pi-bridger/`

I wanna run a .sh script that is under `/home/pi-bridger/`. I am able to run it inside the folder by using the command `./runme.sh`. I wanna run the script from any other folder by simply calling it.

Comment: You need to add that directory to your $PATH

Comment: could you please give the answer as a script. I am new to these. Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14637979/how-to-permanently-set-path-on-linux-unix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run it as

```
/home/pi-bridger/runme.sh
```

Comment: You can execute a script using the name of the shell you want to use, and the full path and name e.g. `bash /home/pi-bridger/runme.sh`